# How to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 backup to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am unable to restore a backup from a 64-bit instance onto a 32-bit instance.

Source Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)
```

Destination server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4064.0 (Intel X86)
```

Error while restoring:

> Restore failed for Server 'servername'
>   The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2500. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.4064. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.

Comment: If you need to transfer data, you can create DB with same name and etc. and when use Task Import or Export Data http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/19/10014014.aspx

Comment: @ITBeginner - does it work for you even when you try to restore to an earlier version?

Comment: hi justin i have in destination place only Database and its sys.tables,it doesn't have exact tables as its source DB tables, in this case will it work the solution what u say?, else what step i suppose to do

Comment: Did you click on the "More reading" link in my answer?

Answer (score 7):

Your issue isn't with the 32-bit vs. 64-bit, but it's that you are trying to restore a database on an older version.

> The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.2600.
>   That version is incompatible with this server, which is running
>   version 10.00.4064.

This means that the source DB is 2008 R2, and destination DB version is 2008 (not R2).

The Best way to do this is to Generate the script of Database and execute it on other machine.

[More Reading](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects)

Raj

Answer (score 3):

You can’t do this by default because you are trying to restore newer version of backup to older version of sql server.

Solution for this is to script object and data and then to execute scripts on new server.

You can also try using some database comparison tools such as those from ApexSQL (Diff and Data Diff) or Red Gate (SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare).

[Here](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/restore-sql-server-database-backup-to-older-version-of-sql-server/) is an article that shows how to do this using ApexSQL tools but it’s basically the same process whatever tool you use.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that. And the problem not in 32 bit, but in version of SQL Server. You've tried to restore on earlier version of SQL Server on target server.